# enter column in a dataset to an array

Tags: sas

I have 33 different datasets with one column and all share the same column name/variable name;

> net_worth

I want to load the values into arrays and use them in a datastep. But the array that I use should depend on the the by groups in the datastep (country by city). There are total of 33 datasets and 33 groups (country by city). each dataset correspond to exactly one by group.

here is an example what the by groups look like in the dataset: customers

- UK 105  (other fields)
- UK 102 (other fields)
- US 291  (other fields)
- US  292 (other fields)

Could I get some advice on how to go about and enter the columns in arrays and then use them in a datastep. or do you suggest to do it in another way?

```
%let var1 = uk105
%let var2 = uk102
.....
&let var33 = jk12

data want; 
set customers;
by country city;
if _n_ =  1 then do;
*set datasets and create and populate arrays*;
* use array values in calculations with fields from dataset customers, depending on which by group. if the by  group  is uk and city is 105 then i need to use the created array corresponding to that by group;
```

Comment: If there is only one variable how can the datasets have multiple groups?  Can you clarify your explanation.  Maybe show a few observations for a couple of datasets and how you want the result to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little hard to understand what you want.

It sounds like you have one dataset name CUSTOMERS that has all of the main variables and a bunch of single variable datasets that the values of NET_WORTH for a lot of different things (Countries?).

Assuming that the observations in all of the datasets are in the same order then I think you are asking for how to generate a data step like this:

```
data want; 
  set customers;
  set uk105 (rename=(net_worth=uk105));
  set uk103 (rename=(net_worth=uk103));
  ....
run;
```

Which might just be easiest to do using a data step.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  input name $32. ;
  file code ;
  put '  set ' name '(rename=(net_worth=' name '));' ;
cards;
uk105
uk102
;;;;
data want; 
  set customers;
%include code / source2;
run;
```